# How come Python's unittest does not fail Mongo validation rule violations?

Tags: python, mongodb, validation

I have the following mongodb schema called `schema` in a project called `project`:

NOTE: db refers to the flask MongoEngine.

```
class Number(db.Document):
    active = db.Boolean(default = False)
    condition = db.DecimalField(min_value = 0, precision = 3)
```

And this test:

```
from project import schema
import unittest

class NumberTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        t = Number(
            active = True,
            condition = -1
        )
```

I am expecting the test to fail because the database schema defines `condition` to be a decimal value that is greater than 0. However, the test passes.

Weirdly though, if I add the following lines the test fails.

```
from project import schema
import unittest

class NumberTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        t = Number(
            active = True,
            condition = -1
        )
        # added lines:
        self.assertTrue(Number.active)
        self.assertGreaterEqual(Number.condition, 0)
```

This makes me think that the validation rules for Mongo simply aren't reliable. I've read some places that validation for noSQL dbases (like Mongo) aren't as robust as for SQL. But those seem to be earlier problems [circa Mongo 1.0] and I think Mongo is sufficiently mature (currently running Mongo 3.0.6.) that data validation shouldn't be a problem.

So the question(s):

- What can I do to get this unit test working?
- If data validation **is** available in MongoDB how do I get it to work? (For example it seems that I can get it to work using a [technique like this](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document-validation/), but the documentation uses the `createCollection()` method how would that work using the `class` definitions I've already employed?)

---

**EDIT**:

The failure is:

`Decimal is not greater than or equal to 0.`

**EDIT 2**:

The plot thickens. I tried adding another data validation attribute (see `precision` above). Checking the value of `Number.condition` I get: `-1.000` even though I am only entering `-1` with a *single* sigfig. So the precision is working. Why not the `min_value` attribute?

Comment: Is it changing it to 0 automatically?

Comment: @Untitled123 I don't think so. I've updated the question to address this. It __is__ in fact storing the value as `-1` (even with precision; which is weird). My assumption though is that it should raise an exception if the data is below the minimum value and therefore fail the test. Something could be wrong w/my assumption; but I haven't read anything in the API to contrary effect.